# How much should I touch when I use Lay of Hands?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, paladin

I am playing an oradin. I am currently trap in a Black Tentacles spell. I want to use [Lay of Hands](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/paladin#TOC-Lay-On-Hands-Su-) on myself.

> Beginning at 2nd level, a paladin can heal wounds (her own or those of others) **by touch**. [...] Using this ability is a standard action, unless the paladin targets herself, in which case it is a swift action. Despite the name of this ability, a paladin only needs one free hand to use this ability.

How should I touch myself? What is the easiest way to trigger the effect? It has to be with a free hand. Can my hand touch it self for example? Does a clapping hand or even pinching two fingers would be enough?

I guess I should touch the wound. But here wounds come from the tentacles (so everywhere) and from the Oracle's [Life Link](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/oracle.html#life) revelation.

Comment: -5... How can I improve it?

Comment: You should only ask [practical, answerable questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) based on actual problems that you face. Describe, what is the actual problem you're trying to solve. Explain, why does it really matter how exactly do you touch youself.

Comment: @enkryptor Thank you. I think I see the problem with this question. I edited. Hope it is a bit better like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From a game mechanics / rules as written point of view, **it doesn't matter**. You have one hand free ([Black Tentacles](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/black-tentacles/) gives you the [grappled condition](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Grappled), which only prevents actions needing *two* hands), you have a swift action available so it just happens. Pathfinder, via its D&D heritage, doesn't get into that kind of simulation of actions.

That's not to say you *shouldn't* role play it, but you don't need to. Note that you couldn't do "clap your hands" as that certainly requires two hands; "King Kong" might as well, although you can certainly imagine a one-handed version.

Comment: What about the Double finger pinching?

Comment: @aloisdg personally, as the paladin, I'd prefer to fist-clenching. Requires less finesse.

Comment: @aloisdg Anything more than "I lay on hands" is getting into a question of what your DM / social contract requires. Mechanically, you just need to say "I lay on hands on myself" and you mystically get some HP back, you don't need to say *how* you do it unless something external to the Rules As Written says you do.

Comment: @aloisdg don't forget to hold your pinky out :)

Comment: @enkryptor what is a pinkie? (my favorite search engine shows a mlp pink poney)

Comment: I mean extending your pinky finger, a.k.a the little finger.

Comment: @enkyptor _The wounded man is thankful for your divine healing and impressed by your class._